# How to Sort a Text Date in Access coming from a SQL Crossover query

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, recordset

I have this Access application where I pull in data from a SQL server database where the date is saved as a text field.  I just created the ability for the users to sort the Recordset.  It is very easy for text fields but now I want to be able to sort by date but unfortunately, as I said earlier it is saved as text in this format mm-dd-yyyy.

Here is the sort code I use:

```
Dim strSQL As String: strSQL = "exec Liab" & strQuearyName & " '" & strSearchValue & "%' "

'Dim qdf As QueryDef: Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strQuearyName)
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strQuearyName)
    .SQL = strSQL
    .ReturnsRecords = True
    Set rst = .OpenRecordset
End With
'SortOutput rst
'rst.Sort = DateValue("DateOfLoss")
rst.Sort = Forms("SelectLiabilityClaimForm").cobSortBy
Set rstSorted = rst.OpenRecordset

With Forms("SelectLiabilityClaimForm").lstbxClaimList
    '.RowSource = queryName
    Set .Recordset = rstSorted
    '.OrderBy = "claimantName"
    .Requery
    .SetFocus
End With
```

How can I sort by the text date, without having to change the passthrough query (I want that as a last resort)

Comment: Convert (cast) the text dates to true _DateTime_ values or, at least, convert to yyymmdd format.

Comment: @Gustav can I do that directly in VBA? I know how to do that in SQL but I want to avoid editing the SQL Server Stored Procedure if possible

Comment: Perhaps. Your code is a bit mixed up, so hard to say, but a query having your data as source should be able to do it.